# Templated class and friend functions

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I have a very simple code where I am trying to create class template. Unfortunately, I am getting error with my code for the friend function.

In the following code 'myArray' as a template class. How can I handle the friend function `operator *(...)` in this scenario? With my current code, I get following error:

```
compilation error:error: invalid use of template-name 'myArray'  
without an argument list myArray operator * (myArray &a1, myArray &a2)*/
```

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int sz = 3;

template <typename T>
class myArray
{
    T *arr;
    const static int size = 3;

public:
    myArray()
    {
        arr = new T[size];
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            arr[i] = 0;
    }

    myArray(T *actArray)
    {
        arr = new T[size];
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            arr[i] = actArray[i];
    }

    void prArray()
    {
        cout<<endl<<endl;
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            cout << "arr [" << i << "] = "  << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    friend myArray operator * (myArray &arr1, myArray &arr2);
 };


myArray operator * (myArray &a1, myArray &a2)
{
myArray product;
for (int i=0; i<sz; i++)
    product.arr[i] = a1.arr[i] * a2.arr[i];

return product; 
}

int main()
{
int xi[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int yi[3] = {5, 5, 5};

float xf[3] = {1.1, 2.1, 3.1};
float yf[3] = {5.5, 5.5, 5.5};

//considering template class as integer
myArray <int>a1;
myArray <int>a2; 
a1 = xi;
a2 = yi;

a1.prArray();
a2.prArray();
cout<<"Interger class..."<<endl;
myArray <int>a3;
a3 = a1 * a2;
a3.prArray();

/*//considering template class as float
myArray <float>b1, <float>b2; 
b1 = xi;
b2 = yi;

b1.prArray();
b2.prArray();
cout<<"Float class..."<<endl;
myArray <float>b3;
b3 = b1 * b2;
b3.prArray();*/
}
```

Comment: `template<class T> myArray<T> operator * (myArray<T> &a1, myArray<T> &a2)` consider using const references.

Comment: The definition (implementation) of your `operator*()` needs to be templated as well.   `template<class T> myArray<T> operator*(const myArray<T> &a1, const myArray<T> &a2)`.   Usage of `myArray` in the function may also require the same treatment.   The compiler doesn't magically associate your class template with its friend declaration with the subsequent definition, for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: Hi SergeyA, 
May I know the explanation why const references are required.

Hi Peter,
I am getting following errors:
with following code changes
1. without const refernce
friend myArray<T> operator* (myArray<T> &arr1, myArray<T> &arr2);  //in class
template <typename T>
myArray<T> operator* (myArray<T> &a1, myArray<T> &a2)
{
 myArray <T> product;
Error::::undefined reference to `operator*(myArray<int>&, myArray<int>&)'

Thanks for both for your responses...

Comment: when i made it as const reference... following is the error
undefined reference to `operator*(myArray<int> const&, myArray<int> const&)'

Answer (score 0):

Move the body of `operator*` into the body of the class:

```
friend myArray operator * (myArray &arr1, myArray &arr2) {
  myArray product;
  for (int i=0; i<sz; i++)
    product.arr[i] = a1.arr[i] * a2.arr[i];

  return product; 
}
```

Also:

```
myArray operator*=(myArray const& arr2)& {
  for (int i=0; i<sz; i++)
    arr[i] *= a2.arr[i];

  return *this;
}
friend myArray operator * (myArray arr1, myArray const& arr2) {
  arr1*=arr2;
  return arr1; 
}
```

with efficient move this reduces temporary objects created.

Comment: Hi Yakk, 
Thanks for your response. But I want the result to be stored in the 3rd object not to modify both operands of operator '*'.

Comment: @raj that is what my code does; it takes the lhs by value ( so it  makes a copy ).  As move should be nearly free with your type,  this means `x = a * b * c * d` only creates one `myArray`, then efficiently reuses a move of it on later `*`, then stores it in `x`.  Naive `operator*( const&, const& )` creates a new `myArray` each `*` then throws it away.

Answer (score 0):

//Finally I define the friend function in the class itself along with the suggestions made by Peter.... so the final code is...Thanks all for your help

But still didn't understand why we made it as const parameters...?

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class myArray
{
    T *arr;
    const static int size = 3;

public:
    myArray()
    {
        arr = new T[size];
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            arr[i] = 0;
    }

    myArray(T *actArray)
    {
        arr = new T[size];
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            arr[i] = actArray[i];
    }

    void prArray()
    {
        cout<<endl<<endl;
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            cout << "arr [" << i << "] = "  << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    friend myArray<T> operator* (const myArray<T>& a1, const myArray<T>& a2)
    {
        myArray <T> product;
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            product.arr[i] = a1.arr[i] * a2.arr[i];

        return product; 
    }
};

int main()
{
int xi[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int yi[3] = {5, 5, 5};

float xf[3] = {1.1, 2.1, 3.1};
float yf[3] = {5.5, 5.5, 5.5};

//considering template class as integer
myArray <int>a1;
myArray <int>a2; 
a1 = xi;
a2 = yi;

a1.prArray();
a2.prArray();
cout<<"Interger class..."<<endl;
myArray <int>a3;
a3 = a1 * a2;
a3.prArray();

//considering template class as float
myArray <float>b1;
myArray <float>b2; 
b1 = xf;
b2 = yf;

b1.prArray();
b2.prArray();
cout<<"Float class..."<<endl;
myArray <float>b3;
b3 = b1 * b2;
b3.prArray();
}
```